# "No operating system found" on boot after secondary drive died

Tags: hard-drive, boot, hard-drive-recovery

I’m at a loss currently. Taking the data loss I’ve had on the secondary drive, I have many important bits on my primary Windows OS drive.

My main drive is visible is BIOS, my secondary drive is not, so I’ve completely disconnected it.

I've tried the following:

1. Connected and disconnected my primary sdd m1 stick
2. Made a Windows USB and started the repair program, no results
3. With the Windows USB initiated the command prompt and accessed my drive just fine (i.e. can see files etc)
4. With the Windows USB initiated the command prompt and tried `bootrec` repair commands

`/fixmbr` works successfully (does not solve the problem however) `/fixboot` yields "Access is denied". However all the solution to this problem doesn't seem to work, I’ve tried:

1. `diskpart`, searching for an EFI partition but concluded that it is an MBR formatted drive
2. `diskpart`, selected the main volume and making that volume active

None of these tries made any differences
`/rebuildbcd` yields unsuccessful results as well

Is there anything else I can do to fix this? Don’t hesistate to refer me to a guide, I’ll gladly follow it.

@user1868569

[image]

@Harrymc
[image]

@user1868569 list par
[image]

@user1868569 dir /a F:
[image]

Comment: Can you start with the Windows ISO boot USB and recover the data on the main drive?

Comment: Can you post the list of partitions/volumes on the disk? Note that post-XP, it is usually _not_ the main Windows volume that needs to be active, but the smaller "Microsoft reserved partition" before it (i.e. the standard Windows layout on BIOS systems kinda mimics an EFI system partition).

Comment: @John - Yes, that is my Plan B option, and then just format the drive. I would however like to get into the operating system. There is some programs that I need to extract data from (if possible)

Comment: @user1686 See screenshot here, but i've tried now to select both vol 0 and 1, but still getting no operating system found unfortunately.

Comment: What do you see in `list part`? The volume list is aggregated from all disks, so it's unclear if `F` belongs to the same disk as `C`. What does `dir /a F:\ ` reveal?

Comment: @user1686 i've attched screenshots of both :)

Comment: The magic command is `bcdboot`. Please verify that C: is your Windows OS partition. // Due to Windows’ sometimes idiotic Setup, your boot partition was probably on the drive that died. This is not a critical problem in any way.

Comment: I've verified that C is my windows drive

Answer (score 2):

Although Windows is installed on the good disk, you were apparently
booting from the bad one.

To re-establish the boot code, you need a Windows boot external disk (USB),
or a Recovery Drive if you have created one, then run Startup Repair.

For the procedure to follow, see the article
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

---

As Startup Repair cannot repair the disk, it seems like the disk
is in a bad shape.

Use a Linux Live boot to save your data, then reinstall Windows.
Re-format the disk while installing, using a Slow (not Quick) format,
so as to find out any bad spots on the disk.

I don't know what has caused such damage to your disks, but if it
is possible that it was a power surge, you should protect your
computer against it happening again.

Comment: Startup repair doesn't find anything. See screenshot

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: I don't think my SSD m1 drive is damaged. My 2nd HDD is however clicking. I'll try to reinstall with slow format

Answer (score 2):

In the recovery Command Prompt you already have, type the following:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /f BIOS
```

Done! (The `/f BIOS` is just to make sure nothing funky happens.)

In case it fails, you may have to set your C: partition active, using `diskpart`:

```
select disk 0
select partition 1
active
```

This entire procedure will put the boot files on your Windows partition, which is not what Windows does by default. Still, it’s totally fine and how stuff worked in the now-distant past.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnecting your secondary drive may have changed the boot order. Please look into your (UEFI)-Bios that the boot settings point to your primary drive.  This is the first thing to verify before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have functional access to the second drive, these steps worked for me:

1. Boot to Windows and open Disk Manager. Mark drive C: on the SSD as "active". You do it with a right-click on the partition.
2. To copy the boot files to the original drive. Go to the command prompt (or recovery command prompt), and run:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f BIOS
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f UEFI
```